# Error on page: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I get this error on my Details view page:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.cpd_certificates_65AF30842281867E2F4F6A1026590271109C12A85C8175394F14EF6DE429CBC7', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[cpd.Models.cpd_certificates]'.
```

**This is my controller :**

```
 public class Default8Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default8/
    private cpdDbContext db = new cpdDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View(db.CPD.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Default8/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        cpd_certificates cpd_ = db.Cert.Find(id);

        return View(cpd_);
    }
```

**Below is my Details view:**

```
@model IEnumerable<cpd.Models.cpd_certificates>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                certificateNo
        </th>
        <th>
            Mark
        </th>
          <th></th>
    </tr>
       @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CertificateNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mark)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Below is the cpd_certificates model:

```
public class cpd_certificates
{

        [Key]
        public int CertificateNo { get; set; }
        public int QuizNo { get; set; }


        public DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatePaid { get; set; }
        public string Mark { get; set; }
        public int? AccreditationNo { get; set; }


        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public virtual cpd_recipients Recipients { get; set; }

}
```

I have two models and I can view the list on my Index. I intended that when I click the details link it takes me to details of certificates earned and exams which are in another model/table. So in short two models which have a PK ID for CPD and FK ID on Cert. Index page show just personal information and this page is fine. 
When Details is clicked it then shows the other model/table data that is the many certificates of that person.

Comment: can you show cpd.Models.cpd_certificates model

Comment: @mohit-arora I have edited and posetd the model fro the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the model into the view as the List of IEnumerable entries instead of passing it as a single entry.
In your Controller you want to show one entry details, but in the view, want to show details of all entries.First you should decide what to show.
For showing one entry details, use this:

controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    cpd_certificates cpd_ = db.Cert.Find(id);
    return View(cpd_);
}
```

view:

```
@model cpd.Models.cpd_certificates  
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";}

<h2>Details</h2>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            certificateNo
        </th>
        <th>
            Mark
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CertificateNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mark)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And when you want to list all of entries, use this:

controller:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    cpd_certificates cpd_ = db.Cert.ToList();
    return View(cpd_);
}
```

view:

```
@model IEnumerable<cpd.Models.cpd_certificates>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                certificateNo
        </th>
        <th>
            Mark
        </th>
          <th></th>
    </tr>
       @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CertificateNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mark)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Please how do I pass that as a List of IEnumerable entries.

Comment: this the error I am getting on this line **db.Cert.ToList()**:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<cpd.Models.cpd_certificates>' to 'cpd.Models.cpd_certificates'

Comment: don't pass list of items to a view that expects one specific item.It will be solved.